# Combining include and where in EF not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to retrieve related entities using include and where statements. Here is the method in my repository:

```
public async Task<PagedList<EventDto>> GetPaginatedEventsAsync(EventParams eventParams)
{
    var user = await _userRepository.GetUserByUsernameAsync(eventParams.username);

    var events = _context.Events
    .AsQueryable()
    .Include(e => e.Creator)
    .Include(e => e.Attendees.Where(attendees => attendees.Attendee.Id == user.Id))
    .ThenInclude(e => e.Attendee)
    .Include(e => e.Organisers.Where(organisers => organisers.Organiser.Id == user.Id))
    .ThenInclude(e => e.Organiser)
    .ProjectTo<EventDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);

    return await PagedList<EventDto>.CreateAsync(events, eventParams.PageNumber, eventParams.PageSize);
}
```

The issue I am having is that all the `event` entities are being retrieved other than just the ones where the `Attendee.Id == user.Id` or`organisers.Organiser.Id == user.Id`. In the most recent test I have done, there is only 1 event where the `Organiser.Id` or the `Attendee.Id` is equal to the `user.Id` so the expected behavior is that just 1 event would be retrieved.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I don't think `Include` actually does the filtering. I think you need a `Where` before `ProjectTo`

Comment: Well, filtering in include clause is supported from EF Core 5.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include Before this EF version it isn't supported and it doesn't work.

Comment: @RichardBarker The `where` is already there. It's after the `Include`. Anton, the version I am using is version 5.0

Comment: Then, assuming the code is correct and working, the issue is in your data. those are the only two places I can see this issue arising.